# Continuation doesn't run if previous is Canceled

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Hopefully, this is a simple question. I have this line of code:

```
Task operation = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.Start(arg), m_token.Token)
    .ContinueWith((previous) => Completed(previous, arg), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The arg object contains the CancellationToken.

If I cancel the task (which I confirmed that it is cancelled) the Completed method is not called at all. Not sure what is happening here and what did I do wrong.

Perhaps this is important bit: I'm using Enterprise library Exception handling block which wraps all exceptions. However everything works just fine when Start throws exception; the Completed is called.

Comment: [This example](http://pastie.org/8527751) works fine; the only difference between this and your code is the scheduler/sync-context (which is a PITA to get running); can I ask you to try the code from that pastie, but with your scheduler/sync-context code (i.e. `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`) ? what happens then?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what *is* the sync-context that you are using? (I tested using the base-type implementation, and again: the code worked fine, even using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`)

Comment: I'll try the example. This is a WinForms application so Completed method has to run on GUI thread.

Comment: Is it possible that you are calling `.Wait()` (or similar) somewhere? That would block the UI thread, meaning that the callback won't fire yet - classic deadlock.

Comment: No. GUI thread is alive the whole time.

Comment: Which thread calls this code? Is that the main thread? I tried with WinForms app, works fine for me, can't reproduce :(

Comment: I've tried it in a winform with the scheduler (here: http://pastie.org/8527800); it works perfectly. What .NET version is this, btw?

Comment: Tried your first example, it returned: continuation; prev-status:Canceled every time. @SriramSakthivel: The GUI thread calls this code.

Comment: It's .NET 4.0 version.

Comment: Can you prepare a sample where it doesn't work? It will be easy to help then. because we can't reproduce the problem here

Comment: It seems that this code is all right and that the problem is much deeper.Turned out everything works fine while the app is connected to Informix database. It doesn't work while connected to SQL Server 2008. It works also if there are no SQL queries in Start method. Still have no idea what is the problem but at least I know this snippet is fine. Need more coffee...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem doesn't seem to be in the code posted.

Answer (score 0):

> The returned Task will not be scheduled for execution until the
>   current task has completed. If the criteria specified through the
>   continuationOptions parameter are not met, the continuation task will
>   be canceled instead of scheduled.

See details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: cancelled tasks still invoke continuations though, depending on the continuationoptions - and the default continuationoptions does indeed raise the continuation (testing locally)

Comment: Yes, according to documentation Completed method should run after cancel but it doesn't.